# Recognize voice when phone is idle screen off?

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

Can i make a `service` which recognize voice even when phone is idle or screen off? I mean can phone listen to what the user will say even on idle state.

Comment: Hope it's not possible. I wouldn't like such an app on my device ;)

Comment: It's very possible. It requires user permissions, but a service is something that runs in the background. It's why Pandora keeps playing even when I turn my screen on.

It's why some audio recording applications allow you to turn screen off to save battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the entire program on how to make that happen.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

That shows how to record audio, the same implementation could be used to listen for audio.

Also, DEV GUIDE on what services are.

Right from developer.android.com

> A service is a component that runs in the background to perform
>   long-running operations or to perform work for remote processes. A
>   service does not provide a user interface. For example, a service
>   might play music in the background while the user is in a different
>   application, or it might fetch data over the network without blocking
>   user interaction with an activity. Another component, such as an
>   activity, can start the service and let it run or bind to it in order
>   to interact with it. A service is implemented as a subclass of Service
>   and you can learn more about it in the Services developer guide.

This should give you all the information you need:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: the question is can phone listen and recognize to what the user will say even on idle state? is it possible?

Comment: Yes, in theory it would be pretty simple for someone to develop an application that runs a service that records/recognizes what the user says.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to aquire a [wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) in a service too keep the phone from sleeping so you can record audio. You can probably stick with a PARTIAL_WAKELOCK since you will not need the screen to be on.

You also need the wakelock permission.

Keeping the device active and processing sound continuously will however not be sensible for any implementation I can think of.

It is a horrible idea for most purposes since it will drain your battery in a matter of hours (tops).

Comment: I don't believe this is true.

I have an application called TapeMachine that I use to record my classes when my screen is off. This proves that you can easily record audio when the screen is completely off.

As you can see https://market.android.com/details?id=com.samalyse.free.tapemachine&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5zYW1hbHlzZS5mcmVlLnRhcGVtYWNoaW5lIl0.

It uses a prevent sleeping permission just to keep it from turning off while recording, but recording while off is just as easy.

Comment: I never said that you can't record when the screen is off. In fact I said he should use PARTIAL_WAKELOCK just becaus he will not need the screen to be on. But the wakelock is needed to keep other resources alive.

Comment: The "prevent sleeping permission" you mention is the one enabling the use of wakelocks by the way (the permission I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: i tried recording with default audio re-coder and it fails to record voice when screen off. i want know how tape machine record the audio even on off screen.Can WAKELOCK solve it? i think it so because tape machine need a wakelock permission.

Comment: Yes. It can most definitely solve it. Just make sure you release the wakelock when you are done with it because every second with a wakelock will drain battery.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working at getting a background audio recorder (while screen is off), and these are the options I've found:

1. A full wakelock lets you keep recording, but keeps the screen on. (not ideal)
2. A partial wakelock would be good, except it doesn't actually work -- at least on my phone. (the cpu is kept active, but the data from the microphone becomes just 0s after a couple minutes)
3. Use a foreground service which starts a background thread that records the audio. This is the best since it lets the screen turn off, while still recording indefinitely.

See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57260468/2441655