# Why AudioRecord is not recording sound when device fall asleep even when I use WakeLock?

Tags: java, android

I'm recording the sound from device with **AudioRecord** and write it to **.wav** file and I need it to keep recording and writing in file even when the device goes to sleep. So I used wakeLock with **PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK** argument. But after the device went asleep **AudioRecord** keep recording but there is no sound. When I opened a **.wav** file there is a silent from the moment when device went asleep.

```
audioRecord.startRecording();
isReading = true;
totalSizeInBytes = 0;        
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize]; //buffer of shorts, getting from audioRecord
            int readCount;
            int state;
            int check = 0;
                        //wakeLock initialization and acquiring
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp:RecordWakeLock");
            wakeLock.acquire();
            if (isWavFileCreated) {
                while (isReading) {
                    Log.d(TAG, audioRecord.getRecordingState() + "");
                    readCount = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    writeWavFile(buffer);
                }
                writeWavFileHeader();
                try {
                    dos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

**audioRecord.getRecordState()** always return true. I don't know what'fs the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608175/2441655) by @Raskilas works!

However, it doesn't include much of the actual code needed, so I've put together a Github Gist which demonstrates the approach: https://gist.github.com/Venryx/e1f772b4c05b2da08e118ccd5cc162ff

It's not a completely finished project (and has extra stuff that isn't needed), but it includes all the important bits, and I can confirm it's working on my device (Mi Mix 3, Android 9), even when its screen is turned off. (I press power and wait 30+ minutes, and it's still logging the microphone input. My previous attempts all stopped ~2 minutes in.)

Interestingly, I didn't even need to activate a wake-lock or wifi-lock; however, functions to do so are included in the Gist as well, in case you find it's needed for your device, and/or to prevent other functionality from being suspended.

Answer (score 1):

You should start recording/initialize `AudioRecord` in independent thread, and start this thread you need from foreground `Service`. Also right before start of recording change thread priority like in example below:

```
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);

AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            sampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            bufferSize);
record.startRecording();
```

Comment: Why should I use foreground service but not just new thread in my activity?

Comment: Because there is much more chance that activity will be killed by system instead of service, as a plus you'll be able to move app in background and continue recording.

Comment: and so I don’t need to use WakeLock?

Comment: I used architecture Activity + Service->AudioRecordingThread and it recorded overnight in background and few hours in the morning while I use other apps and then stop recording manually. So about 10 hours was recorded without interrupts or breaks.